# Cannot run sqlite 3 in Windows 10 x64

Tags: windows, sqlite, dll

I download file https://www.sqlite.org/2023/sqlite-dll-win64-x64-3410000.zip . My PC: Windows 10 x64.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.2604]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>sqlite3
'sqlite3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Windows\system32>cd /d C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\sqlite-dll-win64-x64-3410000

C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\sqlite-dll-win64-x64-3410000>sqlite3
'sqlite3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\sqlite-dll-win64-x64-3410000>sqlite3.dll
The system cannot execute the specified program.

C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\sqlite-dll-win64-x64-3410000>sqlite3.dll
The system cannot execute the specified program.

C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\sqlite-dll-win64-x64-3410000>sqlite3.dll
The system cannot execute the specified program.

C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\sqlite-dll-win64-x64-3410000>
```

```
This file does not have an app associated with it for performing this action. Please install an app or, if one is already installed, create an association in the Default Apps Settings page.
```

my path variable
[image]

[image]

Comment: How to run `.dll` as executable file? I try enter `sqlite3.dll` in CMD as screenshot, but it did not work.

Comment: You need to download the command-line shell executable program, not the dynamic library.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to install SQLite on a 32-bit Windows system, you'll need to download the 32-bit version instead of the 64-bit version. Here are the steps you can follow to install SQLite:

- Download the 32-bit SQLite tools zip file from this link: [sqlite3](https://www.sqlite.org/2023/sqlite-dll-win32-x86-3410000.zip).
- Extract the contents of the zip file to a location of your choice.
- Cut the folder named sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3410000 from the extracted contents.
- Go to your Local Disk C drive and paste the sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3410000 folder there.
- Rename the sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3410000 folder to sqlite3.
- Copy the directory of the file, for example: C:\sqlite3.
- Press the Windows key and search for "Edit the system environment variables".
- Click on "Environment Variables".
- Under the "System Variables" section, select the "Path" variable and click the "Edit" button.
- Click the "New" button and paste the copied path (C:\sqlite3 in our example).
- Save the changes.

*Open your terminal and type sqlite3 to launch the SQLite command-line interface.*

That's it! You should now be able to use SQLite on your system.